# Windows Phone - Can't come back to my own application .SmsComposeTask launcher

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, contacts, launcher

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application.

When I call this method:

```
private void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object o;
    ContactData dane = null;
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.TryGetValue("Contact", out o))
    {
        dane = o as ContactData;
        SmsComposeTask objSendsms = new SmsComposeTask();
        objSendsms.To = (dane.Number).ToString();
        objSendsms.Body = input.Text.ToString();
        objSendsms.Show();
    }
}
```

And then if the only think that I want to do is press `key_back` button:
[this_photo_will_show](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9X9vDk52TgGSDdGbUN3ZFEwLUk/view?usp=sharing)

I know that after I call `btn_send_Click` this  function will open new instance of Microsoft application.To be more specific it will be this function `.Show` from `SmsComposeTask` object.  But how to communicate with this application? How to come back to my own application using `key_back` button?

Comment: What is the exception? (The e parameter in)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll

Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

Comment: when i don't load images it works .. but i want to load my images ; ) I try with [DataContract] and [DataMember] but still do not work .

Comment: Now i know .The problem is when i add `public BitmapImage Image
       {
            get;                              
            set;
        } ` method to my public class . . :( But why ? Someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a resolution .

1.Change a field in class

```
 [DataContract]
    public class ContactData
    {
        [DataMember]
       public byte[] Image
       {
           get;
           set;
       }

        public  byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
            wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wBitmap.PixelWidth, wBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            data = stream.GetBuffer();
        }

        return data;
    }

  }
```

2.Add a class to project :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;

namespace KontaktySilver
{
    public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)

        {
            if (value != null && value is byte[])
            {
                byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
                using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)){
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

                image.SetSource(stream);
                MessageBox.Show("proba");
                return image;
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

3.Add `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectName"`

4.Change binding in xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageConverter}}"  Stretch="Fill" />
```